# what are the types Unit?

Tags: scala

Does anybody know any good reference/s?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: `Programming in Scala` by Martin Odersky explains these very well

Comment: Also [this](http://blog.sanaulla.info/2009/07/12/nothingness/).

Comment: You can find the definition in the API: [Unit](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Unit), [Null](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Null), [Nothing](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Nothing) which I believe to enough self-explanatory in this case

Answer (score 5):

[image]

1. Null: Bottom type for Reference types
2. Nothing: Bottom type for all types
3. Unit: Type representing absence of result

Comment: I'd say that `Nothing` represents absence of result, not `Unit`.

Comment: @ghik, why so? I cite from [Scala API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Unit): `A method with return type Unit is analogous to a Java method which is declared void`. Therefore, I would myself interpret `Unit` as absence of result, it seems more coherent with the API.

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish It's _analogous_ (used in similiar situations), but not the same. The `Unit` type actually _has_ a value, so it can represent a result. An useless result, but still a result.

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish And at the same time `Nothing` type _truly_ has no values, so I think it better fits the definition of "no result".

Comment: @ghik: Just because `Unit` has a value does not mean it cannot represent *represent* the lack of result. Also, `Nothing` is the bottom counterpart of `Any`'s top - if `Nothing` were to represent "no result", then an erroneous conclusion could be drawn that `Any` represents *all possible* results.

Comment: I have not enough experience with Scala to be able to give my personal, at the moment the conclusion I drawn from the API seems to me the best one. @ghik, you definitely have a point, tough, however I a believe `Unit` rep TheTerribleSwiftTomato points out

Answer (score 1):

- `Unit` - essentially a type that has only one value, `()` - it is used in places where you would normally use `void` in Java.
- `Null` - another type that has only one value, `null`. It is a subtype of all reference (nullable) types.
- `Nothing` - a type that has no values and is a subtype of *all* other types. The only valid expression that has type `Nothing` is an expression that always throws an exception. `Nothing` is useful to represent things like for example, an empty list, which has a type `List[Nothing]`. Thanks to that, it can be used everywhere where a `List[E]` is required, regardless of type `E` (this is also powered by list's covariance).

Comment: I think it is important to mention that *there exist no instances of Nothing type*. In addition, please, explain how `List[Nothing]` is better than `List[Any]` (covariance)

Answer (score 0):

**Scala.Null** is the type of a "null" reference. It is a reference type none the less (and so an object of type Null can not be assigned to a value type variable like a Long, which is not a reference type). Think of it as an empty or invalid reference.

**Scala.Nothing** is a class that does not hold any value. You can use it to signal an empty result (instead of using null as you would do in many other languages). It is a subtype of any type in Scala (so you can assign a Nothing to any type variable).

**Scala.Unit** is what other languages might call a "void" data type: it represents the absence of any value. Consequently, "()" is a shorthand for an instance of this class (in fact, there is just one instance of this class).

All this is explained nicely in Martin Odersky's book "Programming in Scala".